# How to get a value of arabic text from input text through change load function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get a value (full names) in Arabic letters from input field so I can run a query using this value. I noticed when I typed in Arabic the javascript code did not work properly and I noticed as well if I make space between the words in English text the javascript code will catch only the first word and the other words will be missed. How can I solve this problem. I looking for the most sample way

HTML Code

```html
<input type="text" name="member" id="member" class="input_field" required />
<div class="modal-body" id="fifth-choice"></div>
```

Javascript Code

```js
$("#member").change(function() {
    $("#fifth-choice").load("menu1.php?member="+$("#member").val());
});
```

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean "a space"? You mean a kashida? Can you change the code you're showing to actually showing off the problem? E.g. show two inputs, one where things work fine, and one where they don't?

Comment: For example like John Steve, there two words with a space in between and not one word

Comment: Okay, but that's not arabic, so what does this question have to do with arabic?

Comment: I tried both arabic and english and I found these two problems

Comment: You already got the right answer, but remember to [write a good question](/help/how-to-ask) in the future. If something is relevant to your question, explain (or better yet, show) why that is.

Comment: But thank you very much for your help. I found the right answer here below

Comment: Just remember that you _always_ need to encodeURI data that you send over a URL (but _not_ the URL itself. Only query _data_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to encode the url parameter by `encodeURI`

```
$("#member").change(function() {
    $("#fifth-choice").load("menu1.php?member="+encodeURI($("#member").val()));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to send more than a value over the same url using jquery load function you can use the below code

```
$("#myDiv").change(function() {
$("#fifth-choice").load("menu1.php?member=" + encodeURI($("#member").val()) + "&id=" + encodeURI($("#id").val()) + "&doc=" + encodeURI($("#doc").val()));
});
```

I hope this could help